# Setup GRUB after windows installed in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I used to have both windows and Linux on my laptop, for some reasons I have deleted the windows partition and I had to install windows back into it.

My problem is how to have Grub back to select my boot without having to go into the bios.

I still have the EFI partition at the beguining of my drive:

```bsh
[ geoffroy@DESKTOP-M9IJ9RC ~ ] -> sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] Mot de passe de geoffroy : 
Désolé, essayez de nouveau.
[sudo] Mot de passe de geoffroy : 
Disque /dev/nvme0n1 : 238,49 GiB, 256060514304 octets, 500118192 secteurs
Modèle de disque : LENSE30256GMSP34MEAT3TA                 
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : gpt
Identifiant de disque : 3DE484CC-3E40-4C0D-9174-8951A3C26A65

Périphérique       Début       Fin  Secteurs Taille Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M Système EFI
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Réservé Microsoft
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296 120567807 120000512  57,2G Données de base Microsoft
/dev/nvme0n1p4 498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Environnement de récupération Windows
/dev/nvme0n1p5 120567808 136566783  15998976   7,6G Partition d'échange Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p6 136566784 186566655  49999872  23,9G Système de fichiers Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p7 186566656 497115135 310548480 148,1G Système de fichiers Linux

Les entrées de la table de partitions ne sont pas dans l'ordre du disque.


Disque /dev/sda : 119,26 GiB, 128043712512 octets, 250085376 secteurs
Modèle de disque : SD/MMC          
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0x00000000

Périphérique Amorçage Début       Fin  Secteurs Taille Id Type
/dev/sda1             32768 250085375 250052608 119,2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Is there a safe way to do it?

Comment: If both systems are UEFI installs, and Windows fast start up is off, you just need to run this: `sudo update-grub` which also runs os-prober. Note that Windows updates will turn fast start up back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
 Grub only boots working Windows, so if issues with Windows, you should always be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu ( same key you used to select to boot flash drive installers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried ```update-grub``` but it is not working, I use fedora 31. I cannot find a way to install it back.

Comment: Ubuntu uses sudo update-grub to call the mkconfig command. With Fedora you have to run the `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` as an administrator. Or this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152222/equivalent-of-update-grub-for-rhel-fedora-centos-systems