# Fix grub to boot correctly into CentOS

Tags: centos, boot, partition, grub2, grub2-mkconfig

I had a dual-boot computer with windows and CentOS 8 [A] on it, each one in different partitions. I created a new partition and successfully installed CentOS Stream [B] on it, but now I'm unable to boot into [A].

How can I fix it?

**Further details**
Disk partitions:

```
/dev/nvm...p1: /boot
/dev/nvm...p2 to /dev/nvm...p4: not relevant
/dev/nvm...p5: /home partition of [A]
/dev/nvm...p6: swap
/dev/nvm...p7: xfs
/dev/nvm...p8: Logival volume with three subpartitions(?).
    - /dev/cl/root: /root of [A]
    - /dev/cl/home: Not in use.
    - /dev/cl/swap: swap created when installing [A]
/dev/nvm...p9: xfs
/dev/nvm...p10: Logival volume with two subpartitions(?).
    - /dev/cs/root: [B]
    - /dev/cs/swap: swap created when installing [B]
```

What have I tried?:

After booting into [B], I first substituted all references to `cs/root` with `cl/root` in the file `/etc/default/grub`. After that I executed `grub2-mkconfig -o "$(readlink -e /etc/grub.cfg)"`, as I had read in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152222/equivalent-of-update-grub-for-rhel-fedora-centos-systems).

After rebooting, four entries with CentOS 8 appear in the grub menu. However, when I try to boot into anyone of them, the system enters an emergency mode and shows the following error: `[Failed] Failed to start Switch Root.` Running `systemctl status initrd-switch-root.service`, as proposed [here](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=61232), results in the error description `Failed to switch root: Specified switch root path '/sysroot' does not seem to be an OS tree. os-release file is missing.`. I've tried the solution proposed there (remounting `/sysroot` and creating an `etc/os-release` file inside of it), but it doesn't work. Under the main tree there is already an existing `/etc/os-release` file in it. At this point, `/dev/cl/home` is mounted in `/sysroot`.

What else can I do? Many thanks!